How to use Excel to find the nth date based on the size of the list of those dates
I have a table like this one with date values for planned and actual dates



Study Acronym
Milestone short name
Actuals
Planned




STUDY1
SCON




STUDY1
SCON

21/08/2023


STUDY1
SCON

31/08/2023


STUDY1
SCON

21/09/2023


STUDY1
SCON

02/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON

06/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON

20/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON

27/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON

02/11/2023


STUDY1
SCON

29/11/2023


STUDY1
SCON

01/02/2024


STUDY1
SCON

21/03/2024


STUDY1
SCON

06/12/2024


STUDY1
SCON
25/08/2023
25/08/2023


STUDY1
SCON
18/09/2023
18/09/2023


STUDY1
SCON
19/09/2023
19/09/2023


STUDY1
SCON
21/09/2023
21/09/2023


STUDY1
SCON
06/10/2023
06/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON
09/10/2023
09/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON
09/10/2023
11/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON
11/10/2023
10/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON
12/10/2023
04/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON
24/10/2023
20/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON
25/10/2023
20/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON
01/11/2023
10/11/2023


STUDY1
SCON
09/11/2023
08/11/2023


STUDY1
SCON
22/11/2023
06/10/2023


STUDY1
SCON
09/12/2023
09/12/2023


STUDY1
SCON
12/12/2023
08/12/2023


STUDY1
SCON
10/01/2024
31/01/2024


STUDY1
SCON
12/01/2024
31/01/2024


STUDY1
SCON
01/02/2024
01/02/2024


STUDY1
SCON
05/02/2024
05/02/2024


STUDY1
SCON
05/02/2024
08/02/2024


STUDY1
SCON
27/02/2024
27/02/2024


STUDY1
SCON
18/03/2024
18/03/2024


STUDY1
SCON
20/03/2024
02/02/2024


STUDY1
SCON
20/03/2024
06/03/2024


STUDY1
SCON
21/03/2024
06/02/2024


STUDY1
SCON
21/03/2024
21/03/2024


STUDY1
SCON
22/03/2024
29/03/2024


STUDY1
SCON
30/04/2024
30/04/2024


STUDY1
SCON
13/06/2024
13/06/2024


STUDY1
SCON
25/06/2024
08/12/2023



I want to automate an equation/formula/macro to calculate the date that 25% SCON occurred. I was able to do it manually with the following steps. There must be a way to remove manual steps here, as I have to repeat this calculation for over 50 tables.
The steps I took:



Count number of planned SCON dates for Study 1




Multiply this number by 0.25 to find the 25%th date value = n




Go down list of ACTUAL dates and count the nth value




Find the date associated with this value



By using the table above, this manual working returned: 44 Planned SCON dates, 25% of this is the 11th date. So the value I need is the 11th date value in the Actuals column : 25-10-23
Is there a way to make this more intuitive/simpler? Or a way to automate it so that I don't have to manually take the 4 steps above each time.
I have included an image of the table with the date highlighted as i've worked it out. 
Any and all help would be massively appreciated!!!

If you have Excel 365, you can use a formula as well:
=LET(cntRows,ROWS(FILTER(Tabelle1,(Table1[Study Acronym]="STUDY1"))),
resultRow,cntRows/4,
INDEX(FILTER(Tabelle1[Actuals],Table1[Actuals]<>""),resultRow))


It first counts the number of rows - filtered by the Study name.
Then divides the result by 4  (= 25%)
Then uses INDEX and FILTER to return the result.

Don't forget to format the cell as date!


what happens if row 15 and 16 of column B contained something else than SCON or column A something else than STUDY1?
PS Using a table is a good idea.

=LET(cond,(Tabelle1[Study Acronym]="STUDY1")*(Tabelle1[Milestone short name]="SCON"),cntRows,ROWS(FILTER(Tabelle1,cond*(Tabelle1[Planned]<>""))), resultRow,ROUNDUP(cntRows/4,), INDEX(FILTER(Tabelle1[Actuals],cond*(Tabelle1[Actuals]<>"")),resultRow)) 

I think there is not enough information in the question ... but yes, it could make sense to do some more filtering

=LET(i,(A2:A45=A2)*(B2:B45="SCON"),INDEX(TOCOL(IFS(i,IFS(C2:C45,C2:C45)),2),ROUNDUP(ROWS(TOCOL(IFS(i,IFS(D2:D45,D2:D45)),2))/4,)))
First i is declared: an array on the rows containing "STUDY1" (equal to A2) in column A and "SCON" in column B.
Next we use IFS to create an error on all 0 values in the i array and another IFS to create an error on non value cells in given range. the 2 argument in TOCOL filters out all errors and only the date values remain. so if we count the rows of the "filtered" D-column values and divide by 4 (equals *25%) and round up to integer, we can use that inside the indexed "filtered" C-column values.

Nth Value Based on List

I used 0.5 instead of 0.25 to get multiple results for a small dataset.
I used >0. You might consider <>"".
I used INT. You might consider a flavor of ROUND.

=LET(s,Table2[Study Acronym],m,Table2[Milestone short name],
        a,Table2[Actuals],p,Table2[Planned],factor,0.5,
    u,s&"|"&m,
    d,DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(u),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        f,u=r,
        fn,INT(ROWS(FILTER(p,f*(p>0)))*factor),
        VSTACK(rr,IFERROR(CHOOSEROWS(
           FILTER(a,f*(a>0)),fn),""))))),1),
    HSTACK(UNIQUE(HSTACK(s,m)),d))



You can automate this process with a bit of VBA in Excel. Here's how you can do that.
Open your Excel file and press ALT + F11 to open the VBA editor. Then, insert a new module by clicking Insert > Module, and paste the following code:
Sub Calculate25PercentSCON()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim plannedCount As Long
    Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim actualDates As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Count the number of planned SCON dates
    plannedCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("E2:E" & lastRow))
    
    ' Calculate the 25% index
    targetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(plannedCount * 0.25, 0)
    
    ' Find the corresponding actual date
    Set actualDates = ws.Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
    
    i = 0
    For Each cell In actualDates
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If i = targetRow Then
            MsgBox "The 25% SCON date is: " & cell.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

The macro counts the planned dates, finds the 25% index, then locates and shows the corresponding date in the actuals column. You just run it and it tells you the 25% SCON date.

Since you mentioned that you have to use this for more than 50 tables, you may want to create a named function in the workbook (you could use any of the nice solutions already provided). Here's an example using a named function.

Steps
Define a formula act_date with parameters for input ranges and criteria (r_s, r_ms, r_act, r_pl, study, ms)

Test this in a cell

=LAMBDA(r_s,r_ms,r_act,r_pl,study,ms, LET(
study_and_ms_matched, COUNTIFS(r_s, study, r_ms, ms),
has_value, LAMBDA(a, LEN(TRIM(a)) > 0),
_25th_percent_pl, ROUNDUP(0.25 * ROWS(FILTER(r_pl, has_value(r_pl) > 0) * study_and_ms_matched), 0),
act_date_at_25th, INDEX(FILTER(r_act, has_value(r_act) * study_and_ms_matched), _25th_percent_pl), act_date_at_25th)
)($A$2:$A$45, $B$2:$B$45, $C$2:$C$45, $D$2:$D$45, "STUDY1", "SCON")


Store study and milestone matches to use them later; COUNTIFS returns 1 if both are matched
Define helper function has_value to test for empty cells - optional
_25th_percent_pl match both conditions by using has_value(r_pl) > 0) * study_and_ms_matched; please change ROUNDUP if needed
Test by providing parameters ($A$2:$A$45, $B$2:$B$45, $C$2:$C$45, $D$2:$D$45, "STUDY1", "SCON")


Add the LAMBDA part (without the parameters) in Name Manager with name and description. When defined  with workbook scope, the function is available in all worksheets. It will be available in other workbooks also when you copy one the worksheets to those.



Test it by entering in a cell:

=act_date($A$2:$A$45, $B$2:$B$45, $C$2:$C$45, $D$2:$D$45, "STUDY1", "SCON")

Optional - add conditional formatting for the Actuals ' range.

I use Excel Labs | Microsoft Garage for entering and testing long formulas.
=LAMBDA(r_s, r_ms, r_act, r_pl, study, ms,
    LET(
        study_and_ms_matched, COUNTIFS(r_s, study, r_ms, ms),
        has_value, LAMBDA(a, LEN(TRIM(a)) > 0),
        _25th_percent_pl, ROUNDUP(
            0.25 *
                ROWS(
                    FILTER(r_pl, has_value(r_pl) > 0) *
                        study_and_ms_matched
                ),
            0
        ),
        act_date_at_25th, INDEX(
            FILTER(r_act, has_value(r_act) * study_and_ms_matched),
            _25th_percent_pl
        ),
        act_date_at_25th
    )
)($A$2:$A$45, $B$2:$B$45, $C$2:$C$45, $D$2:$D$45, "STUDY1", "SCON")

